# XML parsing with XPath and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, xml-parsing

```
<root> 

<method name="A"> 
    <childcall name="B"></childcall>
    <childcall name="C"></childcall>
</method>

<method name="B"> 
    <childcall name="D"></childcall>
</method>

<method name="C"> 
    <childcall name="D"></childcall>
    <childcall name="E"></childcall>
</method>

</root>
```

I want to read and parse the xml using XPath in Javascript or JQuery and generate an output in html. I am able to translate this xml as-is into html using XSLT. But I am looking to produce a call hierarchy for the methods in the xml, for e.g. if user selects method A in the generated html, it should expand and show methods B and C, and when user select B inside A it should show D and so on...

Any suggestion in this regard would help me to get started.

EDIT: Okay, corrected the xml. Not sure what is wrong with the question about parsing. I feel the question about parsing is still relevant. So again, is it possible to parse xml using XPath in Javascript or JQuery and generate an output in html?

Comment: If you start with valid XML, it would probably be easier, as that is not even close to valid.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: The `document.evaluate()` function described in that document isn't supported in IE, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't support XPath. It used to in the very earliest versions, but XPath was removed years ago. You can use DOM methods to break things out of XML with jQuery.

If you want to use XPath in JavaScript, I would try the new [Wicked Good XPath](https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/) library from Google.